# Продолжить rebase не стейджа все файла

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-stash

Хотел вот так внести изменения:

1. Сделать мёрдж
2. Поресолвить конфликты, застейджить
3. Наделать ещё пачку изменений
4. Часть из них достейджить к мёрджу
5. Продолжить мёрдж
6. Оставшиеся изменения внести отдельным коммитом

Но на шаге 5 выяснилось, что мёрдж на самом деле не merge, а rebase (забыл чекбокс снять). Поэтому выдаётся ошибка

> You must edit all merge conflicts and then
>   mark them as resolved using git add

Что надо предпринять, чтобы всё же получить два коммита - один из застейдженных файлов, а второй - из незастейдженных? При этом меня устраивает как merge, так и rebase.

Приходит в голову стешить незастейдженные файлы, продолжать rebase, потом применять стэш. Но вроде бы он [не умеет](//stackoverflow.com/a/20028585/4928642) стешить только незастейдженные?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, а шнобель откуда?

Comment: Какой чекбокс?! Делайте из командной строки, всё получится!

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно вас понял, то в процессе `rebase` можно делать промежуточные коммиты, тогда весь процесс будет выглядеть:

1. Сделать мёрдж
2. Поресолвить конфликты, застейджить
3. Создать коммит, который будет содержать только резолвы конфликтов (`git commit -m "промежуточный коммит"`)
4. Наделать ещё пачку изменений
5. `git rebase --continue`

Тогда ветка будет выглядеть примерно так:

- Коммит "Пачка изменений"
- Коммит "Резолв конфликтов"
- Коммиты из родительской ветки...

Comment: Нельзя. Ошибка же в вопросе.

Comment: @Qwertiy, `git commit` эту ошибку выдает? Она же вроде при `git rebase --continue` вываливается, а коммиты можно делать

Comment: Вот коммит я не догадался попробовать...